# How to make my PHP code shorter and simplier because mine is long compared to my colleagues but i dont want to copy their code

Tags: php, laravel, api

Good day!
my code for reading a text file in PHP laravel is very long. and some of my colleagues said that it can be shorter and neat. can someone help me? 
Thanks in advance! :)
here is the text file data:

```
john,male,20,200,174
joe,male,24,157,166
bea,female,18,153,160
edd,male,30,180,180
```

here is my code for read text file:

```
        $newArray = array();
        foreach(explode(PHP_EOL, Storage::get('upload/test.txt')) as $key => $line) {
            array_push($newArray, explode(',', $line)); 
        }
        $finalArray = array();
        foreach($newArray as $key) {
                $key = [
                            "name" => $key[0],
                            "sex" => $key[1],
                            "age" => $key[2],
                            "height" => $key[3],
                            "weight" => $key[4],
                        ];
                        array_push($finalArray, $key); 
        }
        die(json_encode($finalArray));
```

output:

```
[
    {
        "name": "john",
        "sex": "male",
        "age": "20",
        "height": "200",
        "weight": "174"
    },
    {
        "name": "joe",
        "sex": "male",
        "age": "24",
        "height": "157",
        "weight": "166"
    },
    {
        "name": "bea",
        "sex": "female",
        "age": "18",
        "height": "153",
        "weight": "160"
    },
    {
        "name": "edd",
        "sex": "male",
        "age": "30",
        "height": "180",
        "weight": "180"
    }
]
```

I Just want to make my code shorter with the same output. Thank you :)

Comment: What is the "test.txt" file text. Can you please add some simple code

Comment: can you show your output of both for each?

Comment: You loop the same thing twice. Just merge the two loops and your done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something similar to this if its not a `csv` file:

```
$newArray = [];
$keys = ['name', 'sex', 'age', 'height', 'weight'];
foreach(explode(PHP_EOL, $lines) as $key => $line) {
    $finalise = [];
    foreach( explode(',', $line) as $i => $value){
        $finalise[ $keys [ $i ] ] = $value;       
    }
    array_push($newArray, $finalise); 
}
die(json_encode($newArray));
```

Replacing `$lines` with `Storage::get('upload/test.txt')`

Output:

> [{"name":"test1","sex":"male","age":"18","height":"180","weight":"110"},{"name":"test2","sex":"male","age":"33","height":"180","weight":"100"},{"name":"test3","sex":"female","age":"34","height":"121","weight":"150"},{"name":"test4","sex":"female","age":"20","height":"120","weight":"111"},{"name":"test5","sex":"male","age":"14","height":"140","weight":"90"}]

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to parse a csv file.
In that case you are using the wrong tools to do this.

You should be using `fgetcsv`

```
$json = [];
$path = Storage::path('upload/test.txt');
$file = fopen($path, 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== false) {
    $json[] = $line;
}
fclose($file);
echo json_encode($json);
```

If you need to add the keys use `array_combine`

```
$json[] = array_combine($header, $line);
```

Comment: CSV is a text based Comma Separated Value, the extension of the file does not really matter